# Empty DalekJS test case fails with error

Tags: dalekjs

I am trying to write my very first test case with DalekJS but it keeps failing on error:

```
Running tests
Running Browser: PhantomJS
OS: windows 7 32bit
Browser Version: 1.9.8
>> WARNING: done() not called before timeout!

RUNNING TEST - "_uid"
* 0 Assertions run
* TEST - "_uid" SUCCEEDED

0/0 assertions passed. Elapsed Time: 11.34 sec
```

I have just copy-pasted the example from dalekjs webpage:

```
module.export = {
    'Page title is correct': function (test) {
      test
        .open('http://google.com')
        .assert.title().is('Google', 'It has title')
        .done();
    }

};
```

I have even tried empty test function, but the error was the same.

dalek -v prits out:

```
DalekJS CLI Tools Version: 0.0.5
DalekJS  local install: 0.0.9
Brought to you with love by: Sebastian Golasch (@asciidisco) 2013
Usage: dalek [test files] {OPTIONS}
Options:
  --version, -v   Shows the version of the dalek-cli & local dalek installation

  --reporter, -r  Reporter(s) you would like to invoke
  --driver, -d    Driver(s) you would like to invoke
  --browser, -b   Browser(s) you would like to invoke
  --viewport      Viewport dimensions you would like to invoke
  --baseUrl, -u   Base URL to append all .open()'s with if relative path is
                  given
  --logLevel, -l  Log level, controls the amount of information outputted to
                  the console (0 to 5)
  --remote        Starts a dalek host server for clients to connect to
  --nocolors      Disable colorized output in the console
  --nosymbols     Disable UTF-8 symbols in the console
  --help, -h      Show this message
```

Any help is appriciated.

Shimon

Answer (score 0):

I can answer my question now. I had a typo in first line module.export instead of module.exports.

Sorry for bothering you with stupid question.

But still - could be the root cause printed (something like 'export' is undefined) instead of 'done() not called before timeout!'? :)